# Can't add dashlets on empty dashboard

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

When I remove all dashlets from my dashboard the droppable areas seems to be gone and I can no longer add any dashlets to it. There is no javascript error in the browser console. Having a least one dashlet in each column works fine.

I am on Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.62.0.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe it's a theme conflict - what theme are you using?

Comment: Yes you are right, see below. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of the Finsbury Park Theme:
https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/finsburypark

It doesn't occur on the default Theme and Shoreditch.

Comment: If it is specific to the Finsbury Park theme, please create an issue on the repository you linked to describing the problem.

Comment: Issue created: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/finsburypark/-/issues/17

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, it has been fixed in the latest version of finsburypark.